# Django limit_choices_to with python Index

Tags: python, django

I want to limit a Django relationship using `limit_choices_by` like this.

```
device = models.ForeignKey('Device', limit_choices_to=Q(address[0]='S'),)
```

But this doesn't work.

Basically my related address field contains values like `'TA', 'SA', 'CA', 'SB', 'CB'` etc and I only want the relationship to show the values beginning with `'S'`.

Using a standard Python command

```
address[0] == 0
```

I can get it working using

```
limit_choices_to=Q(address='SA')
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
device = models.ForeignKey('Device', limit_choices_to=Q(address__startswith='S'),)
```